# Show that $W'$ is not a subspace of $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$. Consider $W' = \{v \in V \, |\, v \notin W\}$.

I am not sure about this one at all. So, can we just disprove using contradiction? If $W$ is a subspace of $V$ then it follows that $W$ is a subset of $V$. By definition of a subset $v \in W$. But, it is given that, $v \notin W$. Thus, we have reached a contradiction and $W'$ is not a subspace of $V$.

I know I might be completely off.

Comment: Does $W'$ contain the zero vector?

Comment: **Hint:** vector spaces and as such subspaces must contain the zero vector.

Comment: As for your attempt at a proof, yes unfortunately you are completely off.  Since $W$ is a subset of $V$ that means by definition that for all elements $w\in W$ it follows that $w\in V$ as well.  This is talking about the relationship between $W$ and $V$ so far.  $W'$ on the other hand is something completely different and is in particular the set $V\setminus W$.  For example, let $V=\Bbb R^2$ and $W=\{(x,0)~:~x\in \Bbb R\}$ the "$x$-axis".  Then $W'$ is the set of points in the plane that aren't on the $x$-axis, $\{(x,y)~:~x\in \Bbb R,~y\in\Bbb R,~y\neq 0\}$.

Comment: **Warning: Please don't get frustrated at this follow-up rookie question. May want to make you roll your eyes. **

What if we take the zero vector and tried to differentiate it? Wouldn't we get 0?

Comment: @ChocolateAndMath in order to differentiate anything, you need a *function*, not just a vector. You can differentiate the constant function whose value is always the zero vector (and then you'd get the zero vector) but that doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question here.

Comment: Then, would zero not be an element of W'?

Answer (score 1):

A subspace must contain the zero vector, since $0 \in W$ it follows that $0 \not\in W'$ so $W'$ cannot be a subspace.